# Pixi.js and CocoonJS doesn't work together?

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, pixi.js

I am currently developing a game with Pixi.js for android, so just with HTML5 and Javascript.

For performance perspective of the game, I tried to use the CocoonJS Launcher App. I hosted files on my server. When I'm launching the app, I have this error message :

```
Javascript Exception (Line: 1308 File:'1587683816' Tag:'script'): TypeError: Result of expression 'document.createTextNode' [undefined] is not a function.
```

The problem is on the pixi.js file. What's wrong in the script..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Cocoon doesn't support the DOM - it looks like you're trying to do something that creates a text node.